# CC: Tweaked with ThermalDynamics' ducts move from storage chests to a deposit chest

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I have a gigantic chest storage network connected by ThermalDynamics' Dense Itemducts and I was wondering if anyone had a prewritten code (or enough knowledge of Lua) to pull items from the network to a deposit chest so I wouldn't have to sift through hundreds of chests each time I'm looking for something

I tried local functions defined with (duct, itemName, quantity) but I am not good enough with coding to actually understand why it wasn't pulling from the chests.
I was expecting it to pull a specific number of specified items from the network to the depot chest next to the computer

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to StackOverflow!  If you can add some of your code to your question with as much information as possible including your setup in the game, I'd be curious to look into this.
Please read up on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as it really helps other users of the site to understand your question.  Thanks!

Comment: I dont know how the Thermal Dynamics API works, but i do know that you can interact with storage tile entities directly with a wired modem, and the api is pretty straightforward. Im not sure how different the specs for the modem API were in the older versions, but for the newer versions i had made a quick script to automate a small factory using nothing but wired modems. If you're interested i can try to find it...